# How to focus or change point on child frame

Tags: frames, lsp-mode, focus, rust, lsp-ui

I am trying to use `lsp-ui` package to display some documentation for Rust. When I put the cursor on a type for example, a popup child frame is created but the focus is still on the main window. If I use the mouse to click inside the child frame, I can then scroll with the keyboard but I would like to use the keyboard to change focus inside the child frame and NOT the mouse. Is there any way to do this?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bind a key (or keys) to run the `lsp-ui-doc-focus-frame` command:

```
(use-package lsp-ui
  :bind (("C-h ." . lsp-ui-doc-focus-frame)))
```